# Javascript how to paste the Value inside Username Name

Tags: javascript

My Code is:

```
document.getElementsByName("username").value = "DUBISTFAKE"
```

does not work pls help me im new to Js.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value = "DUBISTFAKE"`

Comment: OMG THANKS ;) wooho it works!

Comment: hehehehehe `(:`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = 'DUBISTFAKE'
```